# How do I check if the scanner is plugged in (C#, .NET TWAIN)

Tags: c#, twain

I'm using the .NET TWAIN code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx?msg=1007385#xx1007385xx in my application. 
When I try to scan an image when the scanner is not plugged in, the application freezes.

How can I check if the device is plugged in, using the TWAIN driver?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe I'm taking the question too literally, but using the TWAIN API, it is not possible to check if a device is plugged in i.e. connected and powered on.  The TWAIN standard does define a capability for this purpose called CAP_DEVICEONLINE, but this feature is so poorly conceived and so few drivers implement it correctly that it is useless in practice.

The closest you can get is this: Open the device (MSG_OPENDS): Almost all drivers will check for device-ready when they are opened, and will display an error dialog to the user. *There is no TWAIN mechanism for suppressing or detecting this dialog* Some drivers will allow the user to correct the problem and continue, in which case you (your app) will never know there was a problem.  Some drivers will allow the user to cancel, in which case the MSG_OPENDS operation will fail, probably returning TWRC_CANCEL but maybe TWRC_FAILURE

A few TWAIN drivers will open without error even though the device is off-line.  Such a driver *may* return FALSE to a query of CAP_DEVICEONLINE. Such a driver will probably do the device-online check when you enable the device with MSG_ENABLEDS, and then if the device is not on-line, you get the error dialog to the user, and so on as above.

Aside and IMPO: WIA is 'more modern' but also much less comprehensive for scanning than TWAIN, and in my experience unusable for multipage scanning from a document feeder. WIA's designers and maintainers seem not to understand or care about scanners other than low-end consumer flatbeds. It's good for cameras.

Answer (score 2):

I started of with the same source code that you downloaded from CodeProject, but moved most of the code in MainFrame.cs that initiates the scanning to a Scanner class.  In order to check for scan errors I call the following method in stead of calling Twain.Acquire directly:

```
enum AcquireResult
{
    OK = 0,
    InitFailed = 1,
    DeviceIDFailed = 2,
    CapabilityFailed = 3,
    UserInterfaceError = 4
}
private void StartScan()
{
    if (!_msgFilter)
    {
        _parent.Enabled = false;
        _msgFilter = true;
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }
    AcquireResult ar = _twain.Acquire();
    if (ar != AcquireResult.OK)
    {
        EndingScan();
        switch (ar)
        {
            case AcquireResult.CapabilityFailed:
                throw new Exception("Scanner capability setup failed");
            case AcquireResult.DeviceIDFailed:
                throw new Exception("Unable to determine device identity");
            case AcquireResult.InitFailed:
                throw new Exception("Scanner initialisation failed");
            case AcquireResult.UserInterfaceError:
                throw new Exception("Error with the Twain user interface");
            default:
                throw new Exception("Document scanning failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I usually initiate the scan event on a seperate thread in order for the app not to freeze while scanning is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

just add this code on your TwainCommand (cmd)

```
case TwainCommand.Null:
    {
     EndingScan();
     tw.CloseSrc();
             Msgbox("There is no device or the scannning has been cancelled.");
     break;
    }
```

this will appear if the systems detect no device or the scanning has been cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the registry.  In:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}` each scanner that's ever been detected is enumerated there in the subkeys.

Starting with `0000`, go through and check if the `CreateFileName` value is blank or has data.

If it has data, it's a connected scanner, if it's blank, it's not connected.

Comment: Unforunately, some scanners report one name to TWAIN but appear under a different name in the registry.  This trick does work sometimes though.

Answer (score -2):

i try do this but dont work good with TWAIN mybe try WIA

mybe try this:

on buton run scanner

```
timer1.Interval = 30000;

switch (cmd)
{
case TwainCommand.TransferReady:

{
..........
}

default:

{
timer1.Start();
break;
}
```

on event timer tick

```
{
EndingScan();
tw.CloseSrc();
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a guess than an answer. And an incorrect guess at that.