# Programmatically ascertain whether TWAIN scanner is turned on

Tags: c++, usb, twain

I am using TWAIN in a C++ program to control an Epson scanner, and have most things working as intended, with one exception:

When the scanner is not turned on, and a scan command is sent I get an error window from Epson Scan: "Cannot communicate with the scanner. Make sure the scanner is turned on (etc)".

Rather than rely on this I would like to check that the scanner is turned on on launch of my program.  Is there a way (using TWAIN or not -  perhaps a scan of connected, powered-on USB devices?) of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this project:

[EnumDevices project](http://www.codeforge.com/article/135485)

on CodeForge which I was able to cannibalise for my needs. I was able to use the logic to generate a list of CStrings containing device names, then just ran through that looking for "EPSON Scanner".

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not achivable with TWAIN. However, you can check with Epson and see if they provide related API to detect / control the error window in their TWAIN driver, so that you can better manage the error display.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100284/how-do-i-check-if-the-scanner-is-plugged-in-c-net-twain) is a similar discussion you can check out.